# How to delete all strings except some specific letters in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

after researching for a while, I didn't find exactly what I would like.

What I'd like to do is to keep an exact pattern in a string.

So this is my example:

`text=c("hello, please keep THIS","THIS is important","all THIS should be done","not exactly This","not THHIS")`

how to get exactly "THIS" in all strings:

`res=c("THIS","THIS","THIS","","")`

I tried `gsub`in r, but I don't know how to match characters.

For example I tried:

```
gsub("(THIS).*", "\\1", text) # This delete all string after "THIS".

gsub(".*(THIS)", "\\1", text) # This delete all string before "THIS".
```

Comment: And what have you tried? What is the exact rule here? Remove all non-capital letters?

Comment: I tried : `gsub("(THIS).*", "\\1", text)
gsub(".*(THIS)", "\\1", text)
gsub(".*(THIS)|(THIS).*", "\\1", text)` I found that (THIS).* means all after. So I thought .*(THIS) is all before and `.*(THIS)|(THIS).*` is before and after

Comment: Please explain what issue you have with this piece of code in the question. So, you have some list of words to keep? What are the *exact requirements*?

Comment: @Sotos, yes I'd like to match exactly.

Comment: So as @Wiktor said you have some sort of list with words to keep?

Comment: thank you for all your comments. I edited several times, I think that the question is more clear now. :)

Comment: No, it is not at all clear. What is so peculiar in `THIS`? Why is `THIS` should be extracted? As I initially asked, are you just trying to remove all non-capital letters? `gsub("[^A-Z]+", "", text)`? Another thing: if there are two `THIS`, e.g. `THIS and THIS here`, what is the result you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it seems that str_extract(text, "THIS") is just I wanted... I would like to have an exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, "THIS")
#[1] "THIS" "THIS" "THIS" NA
```

It is better to have NA rather than `""`

Comment: Is it possible to get "" instead of NA ?

Comment: XRSC Sure. `v1 <- str_extract(text, "THIS"); v1[is.na(v1)] <- ""`

Comment: thank you. In fact, the real problem is : I have "THIS", and "THAT", and I would like to match either "THIS" or "THAT". Is that a simple way ? (I thought about something like : `paste0(str_extract(tolower(text),"this"),str_extract(tolower(text),"that"))`

Comment: @XRSC Try `str_extract(text, "THIS|THAT")`

Answer (score 1):

To extract `THIS` or `THAT` as *whole words*, you may use the following regex:

```
\b(THIS|THAT)\b
```

where `\b` is a word boundary and `(...|...)` is a capturing group with `|` alternation operator (that can appear more than once, more alternatives can be added).

Since `regmatches` with `gregexpr` return a list of vectors with some empty entries whenever no match is found, you need to convert them into NA first, then `unlist`, and then turn to `""`.

Here is some [base R code](https://ideone.com/AUTQ0q):

```
> text=c("hello, please keep THIS","THIS is important","all THIS should be done","not exactly This","not THHIS", "THAT is something I need, too")
[1] "THIS" "THIS" "THIS" ""     ""     ""    
> matches <- regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\b(THIS|THAT)\\b", text))
> res <- lapply(matches, function(x) if (length(x) == 0) NA else x)
> res[is.na(res)] <- ""
> unlist(res)
[1] "THIS" "THIS" "THIS" ""     ""     "THAT"
```

Answer (score -1):

This will first delete elements which don't match THIS and then follows your original idea while storing intermediate result to a variable. It seems that you want to have empty strings for elements that do not match, and last line does that.

```
tmp <- text[grepl("THIS", text)]
gsub("(THIS).*", "\\1", tmp) -> tmp
gsub(".*(THIS)", "\\1", tmp) -> tmp
c(tmp, rep("", length(text) - length(tmp)))
```

`gsub("[^THIS]","",text)` seems to do the trick? "[^THIS]" matches everything except for THIS, and gsub replaces those matches with the empty string given as the second parameter. see comment, doesn't work as expected.

Comment: *"[^THIS]" matches everything except for THIS* is a wrong statement. It matches a single char other than `T`, `H`, `I` or `S`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right gsub("[^THIS]", "", "TttttHIS") gives also "THIS"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [^THIS] matches single char other than THIS, OK. It is possible to state the match with these four letters together ?

Comment: I do not get you. If you need to just extract either of `THIS` or `THAT`, use [`regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\b(THIS|THAT)\\b", text))`](https://ideone.com/xUDagH).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect ! Thank you. Just one little problem: when res is unlisted, character(0) is not taken into the vector. How is it possible to give "" as value to res, so that res has the same length as text ?